# How to Recursively Remove .svn Directories?

Tags: svn, recursion

How do I recursively delete all .svn directories, starting with the directory I am in?

Comment: What platform -- Windows? Linux/UNIX? Something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command to recursively remove all .svn directories on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889619/command-to-recursively-remove-all-svn-directories-on-windows)

Comment: It's on Linux, Debian

Comment: Funny enough, I needed this in the morning when committing something to a mercurial repository. I ended up adding everything and removing the .svn folders before committing instead. And now you come up with this question, apparently Ned's solution is what I needed...

Answer (score 12):

Keep in mind that svn provides the "export" command that provides you with a copy of your working tree, but without all the .svn directories sprinkled in.  This could be what you want.

```
$ svn export /tmp/copy_of_my_tree
```

Comment: this won't work for a repo, you have no access to (e.g. zipped and mailed to you)

Answer (score 9):

If you're working in Linux (or equivalent), you can just do the following:

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Or, better, and as Piskvor mentions, use `-type d` to ensure that one isn't accidentally deleting something that isn't a directory.

Answer (score 7):

In any modern UN*X-like system (Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD):

```
find . -type d -name '.svn' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

find:

- in the current directory
- directories
- with name `.svn`
- and when found, run `rm -rf` on each

Comment: That's almost the canonical idiom.  You forgot `xargs` to reduce the number of `rm` processes needed:

  `find . -type d -name '.svn' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf --`

Comment: To add to @JdeBP's comment: Some `find` implementations also support `-exec rm -rf {} +` or even `-delete` to achieve the same thing.